# How can I use ' in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I cannot use `'` within `''`

This gets syntax error:(
Assuming @post.user.nickname is `John`

```
@message = @post.user.nickname + ''s post'
```

It has to be `John's post`

How can I use `'`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
@message = @post.user.nickname + "'s post"
```

or

```
@message = @post.user.nickname + '\'s post'
```